# How to add numpy arrays of different shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am solving an Optimization problem, and after differentiation the equation becomes

```
y + mu + b_i + c_j + (U.t,v)
```

where shape of the variables are as follows:

```
len(y) = 8992
mu = 2.0
b_i = (943,500)
c_j = (1681,500)
U = (943,500)
V = (500,1681)
```

I cannot solve the above equation since the shapes are different and getting ValueError.

Can someone please tell how to tackle this problem in python.

Comment: what does b_i and others having tuple mean?

Comment: len(y) is rating given by a user for movie , mu is mean of the rating, b_i is the bias term that I created for each user (its vale are zero and is of shape 943,500), c_j is bias term for each movie(its value is zero and is of shape (1681,500)), U and V are obtained from SVD decomposition and its shape are as mentioned above. @Zircoz

Comment: it would be easier if you had written the result using an index notation where all operations are performed only on scalar values. For example:

`A[i, j] = C[i] + B[j]`.

This would help others understand how to broadcast things

Comment: you need to broadcast the values in the appropriate dimension like @tstanisl said. `c_j` is a movie related term and `b_i` is a user related term. Obviously you can't just add them together and expect something meaningful comes out. Try to understand what the derivative means, and what the sum `b_i` and `c_j` should be. Then you should also see that those should all be matrices with dimension (i,j) so you can add up meaningful values with eachother.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add arrays of different dimensions elementwise, obviously, because it is not well defined.

What you can do though, is pad the smaller arrays with `0`s to match the largest array, by:

```
def pad_with_zeros(b_00, b_11):
    b_max, b_min = (b_00, b_11) if b_00.shape[0] > b_11.shape[0] else (b_11, b_00)

    b_min_z = np.zeros_like(b_max)
    b_min_z[:b_min.shape[0],] = b_min
    return b_max, b_min_z

b_00 = np.array([2.2, 1.1, 4.4])
b_11 = np.array([1.2, 3.3])

b_max, b_min_z = pad_with_zeros(b_00, b_11)
b_max, b_min_z
```

and add them together when they are all of the same shape, the only question is if it is what you need?

Cheers.