# Compute mathematical operations on variables of different shape

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I need to compute the value of a given equation. But the variables have different shape.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Dataset:

```
    sample_data_dict = {
     'item_id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
     'rating': {0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 4,},
     'user_id': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}}
    
    sub_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_data_dict)

#computing adjacency matrix
a = csr_matrix((sub_data['rating], (sub_data['user_id], sub_data['item_id]))).toarray()  

#computing mean
mu = sub_data['rating].mean()

#svd decomposition
U, Sigma, V = randomized_svd(a, n_components=5,n_iter=5, random_state=None)

#computing bias terms
b_i = np.zeros(U.shape)
c_j = np.zeros(VT.shape)

alpha = 0.01

Equation to solve:
2*((alpha * b_i) - rating + mu + b_i + c_j + np.dot(U.T*V))
```

Can someone help me by knowing how to compute this, since all the parameters are having different shape

Comment: You already got some ideas in the previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548341/how-to-add-numpy-arrays-of-different-shape.  Have you tried them?  Be more specific about what problem(s) you have.

Comment: `np.dot(U.T*V)` doesn't make sense.  `dot` takes two arrays.  It also has specific rules about how the dimensions combine.  Read it!